# How to force Firefox addon charset/encoding?

Tags: firefox, encoding, character-encoding, firefox-addon

I'm having a trouble with a mobile addon: it shows me the new elements added by scripting with a different charset of the page. E.g. I can read "cuadrúpedo" but the same word in my plugin show "cuadrÂ¡pedo".

I tryed writing the next line to the beginning of my addon, but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("lang", "es");
```

Then, I wrote a "converter function" which replaces the special characters with unicode, like the next line, but it didn't work.

```
str.replace( /&#250;/g, "/xfa&#1470;" );
```

What can I do?

Comment: Could you post some code of what your extension does?

Comment: It's a simple addon test. It only insert a box in page with the word "cuadrúpedo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the JavaScript file is loaded (in Gecko 1.8 and later) from a chrome:// URL, a Byte Order Mark is used to determine the character encoding of the script. Otherwise, the character encoding will be the same as the one used by the XUL file. So, one solution is the HTTP header can contain a character encoding declaration as part of the Content-Type header, for example:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
```

For cross version compatibility you must limit yourself to ASCII. However, you can use unicode escapes – the earlier example rewritten using them would be:

```
var text = "Ein sch\u00F6nes Beispiel eines mehrsprachigen Textes: \u65E5\u672C\u8A9E";
```

JavaScript and Navigator support for UTF-8/Unicode means you can use non-Latin, international, and localized characters, plus special technical symbols in JavaScript programs. Unicode provides a standard way to encode multilingual text: since the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode is compatible with ASCII, programs can use ASCII characters. To receive non-ASCII character input, the client needs to send the input as Unicode.

There is a webpage for text escaping and unescaping in Javascript:
http://0xcc.net/jsescape/

Sources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/International_characters_in_XUL_JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's a matter of text encoding.

Make sure the file that contains the literal `"cuadrúpedo"` is saved as utf-8, not ansi.

Keep in mind that a few key files must be ansi encoded. These are `install.rdf`, `chrome.manifest` and `bootstrap.js`. In this case use unicode escapes, `"cuadr\u00fapedo"`.